# Kotlin: spinner onItemSelectedListener from another fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, spinner

i have a fragment with a BottomNavigationView, a Spinner  and a FrameLayout, in the FrameLayout appears a a new fragment with the BottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener, this is my code:

Fragment ValcuotaEvolFragment

```
class ValcuotaEvolFragment: Fragment() {
lateinit var fragment : Fragment
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater,container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

    val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_valcuota_evol, container, false)
    val menuBottom: BottomNavigationView = root.findViewById(R.id.nav_view_valcuota_evol)
    val spn : Spinner = root.findViewById(R.id.spnAFP)
    val db = DataBaseHandler(activity!!.applicationContext)
    val afpListName : ArrayList<String> = db.getAFPNames()
    fragment= ValcuotaChartFragment()
    val bundle = Bundle()
    spn.adapter= ArrayAdapter<String>(activity!!.applicationContext,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,afpListName)
    spn.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
        override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View, position: Int, id: Long) {
            bundle.putString("afp",spn.selectedItem.toString())
        }
        override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>) { }
    }

    menuBottom.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
        menuItem ->
        when(menuItem.itemId){
                R.id.nav_evolcuota_chart -> {
                     fragment = ValcuotaChartFragment()
                }
                R.id.nav_evolcuota_data -> {
                    fragment = ValcuotaDataFragment()
                }
            }
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        val transaction = childFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        transaction.replace(R.id.frame_valcuota_evol, fragment)
        transaction.addToBackStack(null)
        transaction.commit()
        true
    }
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    val transaction = childFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    transaction.replace(R.id.frame_valcuota_evol, fragment)
    transaction.addToBackStack(null)
    transaction.commit()
    return root
}
}
```

I pass to the new fragment the value "afp" through a Bundle, now i need the new fragment to do something different depending on what I select in the spinner of ValcuotaEvolFragment

this is what i need:

```
class ValcuotaDataFragment : Fragment() {
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_valcuota_data, container, false)
    val afp = arguments!!.getString("afp")

    if(afp == "something"){
    doSomething()
    else {
    doSomethingElse
    }

    return root
}
}
```

this actually works, but only when i change the item in the BottomNavigationView i need this works when change the item in the Spinner, thx

**EDIT**

The EventBus solution works fine , but now i have a new problem in ValcuotaDataFragment i have a RecyclerView, so now i need fill the RecyclerView after change the item in the Spinner, this is how i do it now:

```
    val rcViewValcuota = root. findViewById(R.id.rc_valcuota_data) as RecyclerView 
var valcuota : MutableList<ValcuotaModel> 
val db = DataBaseHandler(activity!!.applicationContext) 
valcuota = db.getCompleteValCuota(spinnerData.selectedItem,"desc") 
rcViewValcuota.adapter= ContentValcuotaMonthlyAdapter(valcuota)
```

i can't access the "root" from the function listenItemChange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so when you're selecting a different item from the spinner, your fragment is not aware of it unless you pass data to fragment. So for informing the fragment, you can implement the interface if you'd like. Or my favorite you can use EventBus library to pass the data.

I'll show you how you can implement EventBus.

First, add EventBus Dependency is the Gradle file:

```
implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'
```

Okay now create a data class for passing data say SpinnerData:

```
data class SpinnerData(val selectedItem:String)
```

Then inside your itemSelected listener, pass the data using EventBus:

```
spn.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View, position: Int, id: Long) {
        // bundle.putString("afp",spn.selectedItem.toString())
        //insted add following line
        EventBus.getDefault().post(SpinnerData(spn.selectedItem.toString()))
    }
    override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>) { }
}
```

Then inside your ValcuotaDataFragment add the following:

```
@Subscribe
fun listenItemChange(spinnerData: SpinnerData){
    if (spinnerData.selectedItem == "something") {
        doSomething()
    } else {
        doSomethingElse()
    }
}

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this)
}

override fun onStop() {
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this)
    super.onStop()
}
```

Now, whenever you change the spinner item Evenbus will be triggered and pass the data to the Subscribed method inside your fragment.

Hope this helps, let me know if you get stuck somewhere.

**Edit:**

This won't work if your fragment isn't initialized already.

SO keep your line inside your itemSelected listener for first time use:

```
bundle.putString("afp",spn.selectedItem.toString())
```

Comment: this works, now i have other problem, i added the problem in the EDIT of the original post, thx

Comment: That's very simple, just declare root as global variable, say var root, and then initialize it in the onCreateView as usual, and then use that root variable wherever you need

Comment: There are other ways also you can use to initialize views, you can use databinding or even you can access views directly by there id, no need to write bilorplate code such as findviewbyid. Read this: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html